# not authorized to perform: amplify:CreateApp on resource... - Amplify Init + Angular

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

According to the guide I was reading, I'm supposed to run in the cmd `amplify configure` and then authenticate into aws console and complete the user creation. It takes me to the IAM page so I click Users > Add User

and create the user. It also says it's successfully set up user as you can see in image,

[image]

but when I run `amplify init`,I get the error
`not authorized to perform: amplify:CreateApp on resource: arn:aws:amplify:us-east...` . I looked in permissions, but didn't see an option for amplify so I'm not really sure how to get past this error. What am I missing? I appreciate any help!

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please go to your IAM in aws.

**CREATE POLICY**

you need to have this

[image: policy aws]

you need to have:

- Cognito Identity
- Amplify
- Cognito Sync
- Cognito User pools

For now, allow all the actions and all the resources... but for security you need to spicify what actions and resources.

**CREATE GROUP**

Create group and add the new policy you are created.

**CREATE USER**

Create user and and the new group.

And that's all.

Comment: I created the role like you said, but I"m not sure how you create a user with the role associated. When I click create user, it asks for user name and access type. On the permissions page, I have the option to add user to a group, copy permissions from existing user, or attach existing policies directly. None of these options seem to have my role so how do I attach it?

Comment: I'm very sorry, for answering quickly I gave you an incorrect answer. I have edited my answer, I hope that solves your problem

Comment: It also needs IAM, CloudFormation and Organizations